# Bit manipulation -- generate mask for first N set bits

Tags: c, algorithm, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, mask

I'm wondering if there is an efficient algorithm implementation for the following problem:

Given an unsigned integer U, make a mask that selects the first N bits of U *that are set.* (Going from right to left, low order to high order)

So for example:

```
f(U=1111, N=2) -> 0011
f(U=1010, N=2) -> 1010
f(U=1110, N=2) -> 0110
f(U=0111, N=2) -> 0011
f(U=0011, N=2) -> 0011
```

Most processors have a "find first set bit" or similar instruction, so I figure in the worst case I can invoke that N times, but is it possible to do better?

Comment: log(N) possible. less steps, but better?

Comment: Obvious question: Are there any restrictions on the space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some recent CPUs have the `pdep` instruction with which this is easy:

```
m = bitmask of n ones
return pdep(m, x)
```

Otherwise a stepwise approach as in @olegarch's solution is probably unavoidable. One with slightly fewer instructions is as follows:

```
unsigned getmask(unsigned x, int n) {
    unsigned x1 = -x;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i)
        x1 = x1 - (x ^ x1);
    return x & x1;
}
```

Comment: It would be preferable to describe the function performed by the PDEP instruction and cite or link to documentation about it.

Comment: PDEP with the mask works a treat. PDEP docs for others: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pdep

Comment: Only downside to PDEP is no portability outside x86 and poor performance on AMD (Zen, Zen2) :( But I can live with that...

Comment: Update: Zen3 has PDEP in hardware (Zen2 was microcode) so it's fast now.

Answer (score 2):

Guess the bit and use built-in popcount to test the guess. If we consider built-in popcount as O(1), then the complexity would be O(log N) (with binary search).

Comment: Could you explain more? Not obvious to me what you mean.

Comment: @JosephGarvin we create a mask, `(1 << i) - 1`. That's a series of set bits up to but not including the `i`th bit. Then we AND (&) that mask with U. If we get `i` right, we have the answer you're looking for. The guesses are over a monotonically increasing range (popcount, which is the number of set bits left after the AND operation), as we increase `i`, which means we can use binary search to find the correct `i` in log(N) time.

Answer (score 1):

```
int getmask(unsigned int U, int n) {
      unsigned int m = U;
      do {
        m &= m - 1;
      } while(m && --n);
      return U & ~m; 
}
```

Comment: `U` should be unsigned, per the statement of the problem.

Comment: The question seeks something better than finding the first (lowest) set bit first N times, but this essentially does that, albeit with plain C code rather than a find-first-bit extension. So it may not be what OP is requesting.

Comment: Changed "int" to "unsigned int". This is not matter, which int type to use. Anyway, there is not comparison "<>" or arithmetic chifts.

Comment: The type matters because, when `m` is `INT_MIN`, the behavior of `m-1` is not defined by the C standard.